# WinAppDriver Appium not finding element visible through inspect.exe

Tags: vb.net, selenium, appium, ui-automation, winappdriver

I am programming on a WinForms application with a gui built using Visual Basic back in pre 2005. I frequently will have elements that are visible on inspect.exe, but when I am running WinAppDriver and Appium it fails to detect those elements.

This is the error I get.

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.'

The error will occur even when my application is the only maximized application. It occurs when I click a button and launch another form. To make sure that it isn't because the elements haven't appeared yet, I have run the command Thread.Sleep(5000) to ensure that the form which is launched has enough time to appear.

This is the line of code attempting to click on the element.

```
driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("vlblYVar").Click();
```

Here is a picture showing inspect.exe clearly finding the element. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it just takes a significant amount of time for the elements in the window that pops up to be recognizable by winappdriver even if inspect.exe picks it up immediately.

I had to use

```
var element = desktopWait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(ByWindowsAutomation.AccessibilityId("vlblYVar")));
desktop.FindElementByAccessibilityId("vlblYVar").Click();
```

Also I had to use a driver that loads the desktop UI because using my program's driver never found the element which would lead to a timeout.

I have a new issue though. When I have a combo box, the elements in that combo box are found by name with inspect.exe, but winAppDriver can never identify the elements in the combo box.